# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setFiles.push(event.target.files[0].name)

    return (<div>
        {files.map((file: any) => (
            <p>Hello!</p>
        ))}
        </div>)

}
```

On the click of a button I am trying to push a value into my state, then map through my state to render p elements, however I am getting the error "Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)" when I try to push into setFiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to typecast to files state using `any`:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([] as any)
```

Also, this line of code is wrong:

```
setFiles.push(event.target.files[0].name)
```

`setFiles` is function you know it.

You should be using:

```
setFiles(files.push(event.target.files[0].name))
```

But react states are immutable. So, you may use spread operator like:

```
setFiles([...files, event.target.files[0].name])
```

Comment: That still give me the error saying I can't push to the array

Answer (score 0):

Since react states are immutable the .push() function will not work, you can either use .concat() or the spread operator.

In order to avoid unwanted side effects you have to wrap your combining arrays logic with a callback.

```
setFiles(oldArray => [...oldArray, event.target.files[0].name])
```

or

```
setFiles(oldArray => oldArray.concat(event.target.files[0].name))
```